# how to trim empty spaces between a word and digits using RegEx

Tags: regex

How to trim empty spaces between string and digits. This regular expression (Version .*?\d$) provides version numbers, but leaves several space between the version and the version number, but I am trying trim the space so that there is only 1 space.

```
(App Version .*?\d$)
Example: App Version               1.1.0.11
Desired output: App Version 1.1.0.11
```

Any guidance or direction greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could match all multiple spaces using `/  +/` and replacing it with one space

Comment: What environment/language is this regex to be executed in?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax might be slightly different depending on what you're coding in, but something along these lines should work:

```js
var str = "App Version               1.1.0.11"
var rgx = /((?:\s*\w+)+)\s+([\d.]+)$/

console.log(str.replace(rgx, "$1 $2"))
```

The regex captures a repeating sequence of words at the beginning `(?:\s*\w+)+`, matches but does not capture spaces between `\s+`, then captures the sequence of digits and `.` characters at the end `[\d.]+`

Answer (score 0):

If your regex engine supports positive [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?<=` then you might use:

[`(?<=App Version) +`](https://regex101.com/r/obEuNf/1/) and replace with a single whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

it's possible that you don't have only spaces, but tabs in between.  The simplest regexp I can think is to search for a `\w` followed by any number of tabs, or spaces, and then a digit `\d`, and substitute it by the same word char, followed by just one space, and the second matched digit.

```
(\w)[\s\t]+(\d)
```

to be substituted by

```
$1 $2
```

[See demo](https://regex101.com/r/woaLkG/2) for details

Answer (score 0):

Regex: `/(?<=\w ) +(?=\d)/`

Replace with: `''` (an empty string)

This will match one or more spaces **if** immediately preceded by a "word sequence (`[A-Za-z0-9_]`) then a space **and** the one or more spaces are immediately followed by a digit (`[0-9]`).

Effectively, the removal of spaces only occurs if there are two or more spaces.  The first spaces is never removed.